# 以上 and adjectives

Tags: grammar, meaning

If an adjective follows 以上, how is interpretation affected? An example: それ以上の大きな野心なんてない。 Should I understand that as "I don't have ambitions larger than that" or "I don't have large ambitions more than that (that is, I have a large ambition, and none in addition to that)". Which interpretation, if either, is correct? please help me understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

それ以上の大きな野心なんてない means "I don't have ambitions larger than that", and the それ (aforementioned ambition) can be tiny or huge, depending on the context. Note that の usually modifies the noun after it.

> - 世界一の会社を経営したい。それ以上の大きな野心なんてない。 (Implies that's the largest ambition a man can dream of)
> - 毎日ゲームだけして暮らしたい。それ以上の大きな野心なんてない。 (Implies the speaker is not an ambitious person at all)